# How to import/export myst markdown from emacs?

Tags: emacs, jupyter-notebook, jupyterbook, myst

I've been starting to use [jupyterbook](https://jupyterbook.org) and it comes with an interesting function called jupytext that can translate md to ipynb and vice versa. Since, I would like to be using emacs for md editing and jupyterbook requires myst flavor: is there a way to tell emacs to export to md using myst flavor? (Well, I'm sure, there is ... the question is rather: has anyone already written an exporter function for that?) Ideally, of course, this could be used, to export ipynb from emacs and import ipynb to emacs org-mode... Am I dreaming too much?